# Is there any plugins for recording screen and voice in React Native with iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm RN beginner and I need to build an iOS APP in React Native. That's my requirement:

- click a button to start recording screen and voice.
- save video file into local folder.
- share to somebody.

I know how to saving file and sharing, but I don't find any plugins for recording screen and voice :(

Have any suggests?
tkx.

Comment: Hi @Jason, you have made the app?

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can use React-native-screen-recorder both android & ios follow this [link](https://github.com/ycswaves/react-native-screen-recorder)