# How to capture an animated View as video

Tags: android, react-native

I am using a react-native Image to show some images from some url on the web. Now, based on some condition I update the image urls in different interval.

I want to capture this whole transition into a video file. However, I cannot find a suitable android APIs (for native side) or react-native packages to achieve that.

I already did something similer to convert an android View into a Bitmap  and then encode it into a jpeg image.

A basic example of what I already have is as follows:

```
componentDidMount() {
   setInterval(() => {
         this.setState({imgUrl: 'some new url' });
   }, 2000);
}

render() {
    return {
      <View style={styles.mystyle}><Image source={this.state.imgUrl}><View>
    }
}
```

Please help me out here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This could help : https://github.com/ycswaves/react-native-screen-recorder

I've not tried this myself, just came across while doing a google search

Possible duplicate question : [Is there any plugins for recording screen and voice in React Native with iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56053465/is-there-any-plugins-for-recording-screen-and-voice-in-react-native-with-ios)

Comment: I have seen this package. This package uses the android MediaRecorder API which only offers to capture either the whole screen movement or video from camera. This doesn't suit my purpose as I have other controls/elements rendered on the screen and this package will record a video of the wole screen. I need something where I can specify which View or ImageView to capture the video from.

Comment: @LauKumra did you get any solution? I also want to achieve something similar