# How do I record the contents in a <View /> of react native app using react native?

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, react-native

I am in desperate need of an answer because I did not find any solution for recording a view (this ) of a react native app, please can someone provide me the solution for it quickly?

Comment: Could you provide some code examples or a futher explanation? What do yo mean by "record" a View? Are you talking about making [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)?

Comment: @PabloCordero , by recording I mean screen recording, I really need  a way to record a video of the contents in my view, and then I will use react-native -fs to save the video in storage.

Comment: @PabloCordero, please if you have a solution, kindly inform me, I am looking for the solution for three two days.

Comment: I don't have any experience doing this. I've been looking for information about it in google, but I don't find to much. I've found a similar question but apparently it isn't solved (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58105104/how-to-capture-an-animated-view-as-video). Have you tried this https://github.com/yutasuzuki/react-native-record-screen?

Comment: @PabloCordero I actually tried that  https://github.com/yutasuzuki/react-native-record-screen before asking this question but it didn`t worked.